# Is muscle ache a possible sign of the body using muscle mass as a source of energy due to the lack of nutrition?

Tags: exercise, musculoskeletal-system, muscle

When doing maximal effort exercise after not eating for a long time (24 hours) before the exercise, and not eating for hours after the exercise, I feel moderate muscle aches the day afterwards. Is that caused by by my body sourcing energy from muscle mass?

Comment: I think this applies to every human who strains his body in combination with not providing the needed energy? It is only the wording that makes it personal (the main question, which is the title, is supposed to be universal, the description was meant to be providing the context)

Comment: I think some editing can make this into a non-medical question. The base question asks if muscle ache is caused by muscle breakdown, and this is an answerable question.

Comment: @MarchHo It is way too broad. Something like How does lactic acid build up contribute to muscle soreness would be an answerable question. There are too many parts that would need to be explained to provide a proper, referenced answer and would be too long for this format.

Comment: @amr - Actually, lactic acid is a fuel, and does not contribute to muscle soreness. That's an erroneous correlation from long ago.